# Linhas da tabela alinhadas a direita

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabela-html

Quero que as linhas da minha tabela sejas alinhadas a direita e o título da coluna centralizado, alguém pode ajudar? O código está assim:

```
<p:column sortBy="totalApontado">
  <f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText id="columnHeader_totalApontado" value="#       
   {messages['quantidade.apontada']}" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText id="totalApontado"
  value="#{row.totalQuantidadeProcesso}" style="text-align: right;"/>
```

Comment: Olá, poste seu codigo HTML gerado, assim podemos auxiliar melhor.

Comment: para melhor ajudar coloca também a foto de como está a pagina e detalhe melhor como você gostaria que ficasse, porque uma explicação vaga vai ter respostas vagas.

Answer (score 0):

Troque seu css ficando assim:

```
value="#{row.totalQuantidadeProcesso}" style="float: right;"/>
```